# How to use my corporate account to login to Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I work at an IT company where I would like to create a Wordpress website, but I need to use corporate ID to login to it so that other employees don't have to login every time but should get automatically logged in using corporate ID (could be auto detection AD login credentials or something else). Ideas are welcome. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Maybe this LDAP AD Integration plugin will help: https://wordpress.org/plugins/active-directory-integration/

Comment: Thanks. That a really great push in a right direction. Do you suggest any tutorial or write your answer in "Answer" section so that I can vote it as the best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this LDAP AD plugin will help: https://wordpress.org/plugins/active-directory-integration/

There is a support forum on the plugin page, I suggest you go there for help.
Or attempt to contact the plugin creator.